# Can not find div embeded in another div using beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to using beautifulsoup

here is my current code

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get("https://www.myntra.com/jordan", headers=headers, verify=False)

src = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all("a")
urls = []

for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'id':"mountRoot"}):
    print(div)
    print("\n")
    for div_tag in div.find_all('div'):
        print(div_tag)
        embedded_div = div_tag.find('div')
        print(embedded_div)
```

output of this code:

```
<div id="mountRoot" style="min-height:750px;margin-top:-2px">< div class="loader-container">< div class="spinner-spinner">< /div>< /div>< /div>

<div class="loader-container">< div class="spinner-spinner">< /div>< /div>
<div class="spinner-spinner">< /div>
<div class="spinner-spinner">< /div>
```

here is the inspect element of the website that I am looking at
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zui3R.png

to me, it seems that it is ignoring the < div data_reactroot>

What am I doing wrong? any help would appercated

Comment: usually when you see an element with inspect and beautifulsoup returns nothing it means that the page is modified with javascript. in your particular case most of the data is stored in script tags

Comment: That page might be loading by JavaScript. Use Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the first rows are cached into the page in a `script` tag with attribute `type="application/ld+json"` like this :

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{ some big json here }</script>
```

You can get the data by choosing the json with key `@type:"ItemList"` and then get the items:

```py
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get("https://www.myntra.com/jordan", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

data_json = [ 
    json.loads(t.text)
    for t in soup.findAll("script",{"type":"application/ld+json"})
]
data = [
    t
    for t in data_json
    if t["@type"] == "ItemList"
]
print(data[0]["itemListElement"])
```

But it will only print a few rows, in order to get the data with pagination, there is an API on:

```
GET https://www.myntra.com/gateway/v2/search/jordan
```

The following will get the first page using the API:

```py
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://www.myntra.com/jordan", headers=headers)

# first page
r = s.get("https://www.myntra.com/gateway/v2/search/jordan",
    params = {
        "p": "1",
        "rows": 50,
        "o": 0,
        "plaEnabled":"false"
    },
    headers=headers
)
print(r.json())
```

You will need to increment `p` for moving to the next page. Also `o` is the offset index, you will increment it by `per_page - 1` each time. For example, the second page will have `"o":49` if you have set `"rows":50`